# Handling Intercepted request

Tags: java, servlets, request, aop

Consider you have Aspect or Interceptor that intercepts all the requests to your controller. In case of Aspect, you can define some pointcuts and intercept request having `ProceedingJoinPoint` object. You can call  `ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` to perform request. And consider you have, f.e., `boolean flag;` that indicates whether to perform intercepted request or not. The question is how to not perform intercepted request if needed.
I added some code of my case, but you're welcome to provide your case (filter instead of aspect or so on)

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void publicMethodPointcut() {
    }

 @Around("publicMethodPointcut()")
    public Object do(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        if (flag){
            return pjp.proceed();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want to prevent your controller from executing?

Comment: Exactly. That's the point

Comment: You'll have to make your aspect behave like a controller. See [supported return types](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types).

Comment: Just from looking at the sample code I see that your advice will not even compile because you have to return _something_ even outside the `if` branch. So in order to make the example a bit more realistic you should think about (and show to us) what you want to return as a replacement for the skipped `proceed()` value.